# Pipe operator, how does it work?

Tags: c#, pipe, operator-keyword

So I have messing around just now and wrote this out:

```
        int i = 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10;

        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        Console.Read();
```

This outputs 15. Why does it output 15? What does the pipe operator do?

Could you give me an example of where this might actually be used.

I understand if this seems like a pointless question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's the [bit-wise OR operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The basic truth table for the OR operator is:

```
  A  B  A|B
  0  0   0
  0  1   1
  1  0   1
  1  1   1
```

So to analyze your case `0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10`, in binary, that's:

```
 0 = 0b00000 
 1 = 0b00001 
 2 = 0b00010 
 3 = 0b00011 
 4 = 0b00100 
 5 = 0b00101 
 6 = 0b00110
 7 = 0b00111 
 8 = 0b01000 
 9 = 0b01001 
10 = 0b01010
------------
15 = 0b01111
```

**Further Reading**

- [Bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Comment: And suddenly it's explained.

Comment: @Plast1k you could have easily explained this as well LOL

Comment: I do not believe I could have!  I have seen truth tables before, but wasn't really able to apply them in this fashion.  This helped immensely.

Comment: I looked at this from something I learned in a Math class for Electronics I took back in the 8th grade over 30+ yrs ago.. lol it's like riding a bike `AND OR NOT NOR NAND` etc...LOL

Comment: Definitely confusing stuff, but you're right, it does come back.

Answer (score 1):

`|` is the bitwise OR operator in C# (and many other languages). An OR operation between two bits goes like this:

```
0 | 0 = 0
1 | 0 = 1
0 | 1 = 1
1 | 1 = 1
```

so in decimal 1 | 2 becomes 01 | 10 in binary, which results in 11 (3 in decimal), like so:

```
01
10
--
11
```

Bitwise OR is a cumulative operation so:

```
 0 = 00000 
 1 = 00001 
 2 = 00010 
 3 = 00011 
 4 = 00100 
 5 = 00101 
 6 = 00110
 7 = 00111 
 8 = 01000 
 9 = 01001 
10 = 01010
------------
15 = 01111
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the bit-wise OR of the binary representation of those numbers. The numbers 0 through 10 in binary look like:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
```

If you were to perform an OR of each digit of all of those numbers, you would end up with `1111` - which is 15 in decimal.

Comment: I think an easier way to figure out the number is use the old `8421` method and where ever you see a `1`, you add the values for example `1001 = 9` if you wanted 16 it would be `10000`